# How do guests make requests in the WestWorld game?

Tags: westworld-tv

In [Dissonance Theory](http://westworld.wikia.com/wiki/Dissonance_Theory) we see the park operators discussing a request from The Man in Black for "a pyrotechnic effect, low yield, two charges". He then lights up his cigar, puts it in the jail cell door keyhole, which blows up seconds later. Another few seconds later, a second cigar blows up in the mouth of a prison guard (who happened to light it up exactly at the same time?)

How did The Man in Black make that request?

Comment: Although there is obviously some time compression I would assume that the hosts are constantly providing updates back to the central control. Since they can see what is *intended* ... that would form the "request".

Comment: @Paulie_D Would it be more likely that the Man in Black striking the match was a signal?

Comment: The cigars were pre-loaded so the park obviously knew about them and sanctioned their possible use. As I said, there is no *obvious* request other than the action we see....I would assume the action we see (whatever it is) forms the "request".

Comment: On the point of lighting up the cigars at exactly the same time, you'll notice that the MiB deliberately blows on the lit end of the cigar to burn it faster. As such, there is some wriggle room for the guard to have lit it before the MiB made his escape.

Comment: Remember, The Man in Black is a very important guest, so the rules are different for him.

Answer (score 10):

My impression during the episode is that the **actions** of the guests act as the request. The Man In Black was starting an action that would lead to an explosion. The park tech saw that the guest expected an explosion, asked for approval, got it, and triggered the controlled & approved explosion.

In other words, guests don't verbally ask. Their actions trigger requests.